# Как нарисовать многоугольник на canvas в android

Tags: android, canvas

Добрый день. Нужно динамически нарисовать многоугольник в android на canvas.
Делаю вот так, но ничего не выходит!!! В чем ошибка?

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        path.moveTo(startX,startY);
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            x[i]=startX;
            y[i]=startY;
            path.lineTo(x[i], y[i]);
            path.close();
            canvas.drawCircle(x[i], y[i], 20, paint);         
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX= event.getX();
            startY= event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: `path.close()` наверное, надо не в цикле вызывать, а перед рисованием. Хотя тут вообще все печально. Вам надо в поле объекта хранить индекс следующей точки в массиве, заполнять ее координатами в `onTouch`, увеличивать индекс, а в `onDraw` рисовать с `x[0], y[0]` до конца. Возможно, лучше вместо массивов использовать списки.

Answer (score 1):

Нарисовать получилось! А вот как присвоить и подписать каждому углу номер или букву!?

код как рисую многоугольник...

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (i == 0) {
                        startX = event.getX();
                        startY = event.getY();

                        x[i] = startX;
                        y[k] = startY;
                        path.moveTo(x[i], y[k]);
                        path.addCircle(x[i], y[k], 20, Path.Direction.CCW);

                    } else {
                        x[i] = event.getX();
                        y[k] = event.getY();
                        moveY = y[i];
                        moveX = x[k];

                        if (startX > moveX - Rad &&
                                startX < moveX + Rad &&
                                startY > moveY - Rad &&
                                startY < moveY + Rad) {
                            path.lineTo(startX, startY);
                            path.close();
                            invalidate();

                            return false;

                        } else {
                            path.lineTo(x[i], y[k]);

                            path.addCircle(x[i], y[k], 15, Path.Direction.CCW);
                        }
                    }

                    i++;
                    k++;
            }

        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```